# Send object informations to another window in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, window

`c` is an object with some attributes, name is one of them. I'm creating a textblock with the name of the chosen object. I'm trying to jump to a new page by sending the informations of all my object; i want to be able to get the information of the object "c" in the other window.

```
public MainWindow()
    {      
        InitializeComponent();
    }
private void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock();
        t1.Text = c.getName();
        s1.Children.Add(t1);
Run run3 = new Run(c.getName());

        Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink(run3)
        {
            NavigateUri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com")
        };
        hyperlink.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(Hyperlink_RequestNavigate); //to be implemented

        t1.Inlines.Clear();
        t1.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);


    }

    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        win1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

}

```
 public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //i want to obtain the object c here
        Console.write( c.getName() );
        Console.write( c.getAddress() );
        Console.write( c.getPrice() );
                  etc....
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to `Window1` that takes a reference to Object 'c'

```
public Window1(ObjectC c)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //i want to obtain the object c here
    Console.write( c.getName() );
    Console.write( c.getAddress() );
    Console.write( c.getPrice() );
              etc....
}
```

Then update:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    ObjectC c = new ObjectC();
    Window1 win1 = new Window1(c);
    win1.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: but now i got this problem:

Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type 'ObjectC' is less accessible than method 'Window1.Window1(ObjectC c)'

Comment: make sure `public` is in front your ObjectC class declaration